# Example of an abelian group $G$ with $A \le G$ but no $B \le G$ with $G = A \oplus B$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, direct-sum

I just read that if $G$ is an abelian group with subgroup $A$, then we could not always find a subgroup $B$ such that $G = A \oplus B$.

I tried to come up with an example, let $G = \mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$ and $A := \langle (1,1,1,1,1,\ldots ) \rangle$, suppose $G = A \oplus B$ and consider $(0,-1,-1,-1,\ldots) = (-1,-1,-1,-1,\ldots) + (1,0,0,0,\ldots)$, which is a unique decomposition with an element from $A$, hence we must have $(1,0,0,0,\ldots) \in B$, by considering $(-1,0,-1,-1,\ldots)$ we find $(0,1,0,0,\ldots ) \in B$ and so on, and as these elements generate $G$ this implies $G = B$, a contradiction to $G = A \oplus B$; hence we could not have such an direct sum decomposition.

Is my above reasoning correct? Do you know any other examples?

Comment: Consider $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $A=2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Or, for a minimal example, consider @egreg's example modulo $4$.

Comment: Same reasoning, if $Z = 2\mathbb Z \oplus B$, then as $3 = 2 + 1$ we would have $1 \in \mathbb B$, giving $B = \mathbb Z$; correct?

Comment: @Arthur You mean $G = \mathbb Z / 4\mathbb Z = \{0,1,2,3\}$. Set $A = \{0,2\}$, then if $B \ne 1$ we would have $1 \in B$ or $3 \in B$, both giving $G = B$ and hence $A \cap B \ne 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your argument is not conclusive, because the elements you list do not generate $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$, but only $\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{N})}$ (the subgroup of sequences with only a finite number of nonzero terms).

A much simpler example is $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $A=2\mathbb{Z}$.

There's no $B$, because two nonzero subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ always have nonzero intersection.

Groups with the property that *no* nonzero subgroup has a complement are *indecomposable* and there are many: $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ with $p$ a prime, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$ are basic examples.

By the way, $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ *is* decomposable: take $A=\langle(1,0,0,\dotsc)\rangle$ and $B=\{(0,a_1,a_2,\dotsc):a_i\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding your last line, I meant for a given $A$, so do you have a $B$ for $A = \langle (1,1,1,1,\ldots) \rangle$?

Comment: @Stefan I don't think your $A$ is a direct summand, but, as I said, your argument is faulty. I guess it can be fixed, though.

Comment: @Stefan If your ideas worked, they would also work for $G=\mathbb{Z}_2^{\mathbb{N}}$, but that it is a vector space, so $A$ clearly has a complement. (Note that $B$ needs to be uncountable.)